# Quasiperiodic dynamics of a System

Tags: quasi-periodic

i understand that, periodic behavior is defined as recurring at regular intervals. Does quasiperiodic mean, that the interval is shifted. If yes, is this shift well defined?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quasiperiodic means that the period shifts, and no the shift is not always well defined. It can be, for example, in the effect of general relativity on the orbit of the planet mercury. For many situations associated with nonlinear systems, the shifts from exact periodicity are not so regular.

Comment: Is any signal with a period that is a function of time to be considered quasiperiodic?

Comment: I think that a signal needs to be close to periodic to be called quasiperiodic. That would eliminate wildly varying signals from this caregory.